# how to unregister content observer in preferences

Tags: android, preferences, contentobserver

I m working on application where i got a task to work on preference so implemented
switch preference where if switch is on  i have to monitor contact database so i used 
content observer and when user switchoff i have to unregister that content observer
have look at the code i  implement

```
MyContentObserver observer;
switchPref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference,
                Object newValue) {
            boolean switched = ((SwitchPreference) preference)
                    .isChecked();

           if( !switched){
            //   Toast.makeText(SettingActivity.this,"Switch is on",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           observer=new MyCOntentObserver();
               getContentResolver()
               .registerContentObserver(
                       ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, true,
                       observer); 

           }
               else{
            //   Toast.makeText(SettingActivity.this,"Switch is off",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

               //   getContentResolver().unregisterContentObserver(observer);
               //here i want a logic that to destroy instance which i created
                 while switch is On


}
               return true;
        }
    });
  public class MyContentObserver extends ContentObserver{
            public MyCOntentObserver() {
                super(null);
            }
            @Override
            public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
            super.onChange(selfChange);
                Log.e("","~~~~~~contact inserted or updated"+selfChange);
            }  

            @Override
            public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
                return true;
            }
        }
```

Any suggestion or help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

That will do. You just have to call unregisterContentObserver with the same observer to remove notifications. But in order to avoid erros if the observar have been already removed add it in a try-catch block

```
try {  
getContentResolver().unregisterContentObserver(observer);  
} catch (IllegalStateException ise) {  
// Do Nothing.  Observer has already been unregistered.  
}
```

You don't need to destroy the instance, just make sure it's a singleton. So if the user turn on again the settings you will recycle that instance.